# I'm trying to figure out how to see how many colors are in an image.

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to figure out how to see the amount of total images in an image and when I run this script only thing that happens on the page is it prints a 00.

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('C:/wamp/www/button.png');
$image = imagecolorstotal($img);
echo($image);
print_r($image);
```

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 3):

Manual suggests that 0 is returned for truecolor images. You can check if your image is truecolor using the below:

```
var_dump(imageistruecolor($img));
```

If it dumps true, getting a 0 return from imagecolorstotal is logical.

Comment: Do I need to convert the image to something else first?

Comment: that would very likely change the number of colours